# Rails nested routes with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use a link_to from my view into a nested route and I am sure I just have my syntax incorrect.  The basic flow of my app is there is a summary that has many feeds which then have many log lines. its  a very basic report

My route is

```
    resources :perfsums, :only => [:index] do
    resources :perffeedresults, :only => [:index] do
          resources :loglines, :only => [:index] do
          end
    end
  end
```

Here is how the rake routes looks for that

```
perfsum_perffeedresult_loglines_path    GET     /perfsums/:perfsum_id/perffeedresults/:perffeedresult_id/loglines(.:format)     loglines#index
```

In my view I have a link to I want to link from the feed class to log lines using the feed ID.  Should be very simple.  My link to looks like this

```
  <td> <%= link_to c.id, perfsum_perffeedresult_loglines(c) %> </td>
```

Going directly to the page by hand works as the link below shows I just can't get there form that link to

```
http://localhost:3000/perfsums/19/perffeedresults/143/loglines
```

When I try to run with that link_to I get. I have tried a few different options here none have worked.

```
undefined method `perfsum_perffeedresult_loglines' for #<#<Class:0x007fad31b60dd8>:0x007fad386d86b0>
```

I do use a link_to to go from the summary to the feeds page fine its just that extra  bit of nesting t hats throwing me off I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's a `perfsum_perffeedresult_loglines_path`, you missed `_path`, which should be added to get a path. And you need to pass two params, look at the path:

```
/perfsums/:perfsum_id/perffeedresults/:perffeedresult_id/loglines
```

You need to pass a `perfsum` and a `perffeedresult`:

```
<td> <%= link_to c.id, perfsum_perffeedresult_loglines_path(perfsum, perffeedresult) %> </td>
```

Comment: thank you for the dope slap this worked    <td>  <%= link_to c.id, perfsum_perffeedresult_loglines_path(c.perfsummaryid, c.id) %> </td>

Comment: @ducati1212 no problem!